# How to develop application for Hide files in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop application to **HIDE** files in Android.The files may be video or mp3 files.So please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: ask James Bond 007@intelligence.uk He should know. :)

Comment: How hidden do you want them to be?

Comment: I want to hide the files from the SD card.May be by setting file attribute hide to true.is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Hidden files in Android are nothing but they have .(dot) as their first letter.

Using **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ()** you can get SD Card as a **File** Object.
Then list the files in SD Card using **file.list ()**.

Comment: I am not getting it will you give some explanation on it.thanks for reply.